# How to break inside if condition in java

Tags: java

i Have below method . which i am calling an boolean method inside it.if that boolean method is true then exit from the block else continue with else block. Below is what i tried. but failed to break the method.

```
public IStatus validate() throws ExecutionValidationException {
    ConfigurationHandler handler = new ConfigurationHandler(getExecutionParameters());
    if (handler.isModelValidationEnabled()){
      //how to handle here and exit here. i need to continue the application
    } else
        this.loggerStorage.getLogger().info(VALIDATION_DM_START);
    try {
        return getDataModel().validateModel();
    } finally {
        this.loggerStorage.getLogger().info(VALIDATION_DM_FINISHED);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If `a.method2()` is true, then the `else` portion will never execute.

Comment: You can still return from a `void` method by writing `return;`

Comment: Judgind by the latest edits this is a simple typographical error and should probably be closed: You just forgot the braces around your else block, thats why the try block is executed everytime (its not part of the else block).

Comment: If the `boolean` method returns true, what should your `validate` method return? (I ask because you have declared that it returns something of type `IStatus`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put anything in the `if` body, the `else` is skipped if the `if` is `true`. But, It would be cleaner to use a boolean negation like,

```
public void method1(){
    A a = new A();
    if (!a.method2()) {
        method3(); //<-- block not entered if method2() returns true.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need to exit from method1()completely. i don't want to continue else
>   part.How can i break/exit here... and continue with the application.
>   If false then execute else part

It is the goal of a `if else` block.

Here if the `if` statement is `true`, the `else` block is never reached.

```
if(a.method2() == true){
   ...
}
else{
   ...
}
```

You could use a `return` statement if you had some other processings after the `if` statement that you don't want ignore in this specific case.
But in this case you don't need to couple the `if` where you want to make a `return` with other `else if` blocks as they are not dependent:

```
if(a.method2() == true){
   ...
    return;
}

if(...){
   ...
}
else{
   ...
}
// do some processing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
if(a.method2() == true){
    return;
}
```

But I really think you should question what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method1(){
    A a = new A();
    if(a.method2() == false){
        continue with method3();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14851452)

Comment: @bsiamionau A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD interesting fact for you - the code listed above is not even a valid Java code. It's definitely NOT an answer. What is the purpose of such answer?

Comment: @bsiamionau Please read the meta-post I've linked in my comment. The answer might be wrong, but it's still an answer. You can downvote it, if it's wrong but not delete it.

Comment: @FelixSFD according to your position, nothing could be deleted because technically, anything posted as answer is an answer.

Comment: @bsiamionau Please read the meta-post I've linked in my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132911/discussion-between-felixsfd-and-bsiamionau).